# MarkLogic 7 - database-backup with rest-api

Tags: marklogic

I'm looking to automate backups in ML7 using rest-api.
Since that's not available out of the box, I figured that I can just add new extension and setup script with curl command on desired schedule.
Sounds easy but for some reason when I try installing my extensions it spits out 'invalid content' and log is showing:

•   `RESTAPI-INVALIDCONTENT: (err:FOER0000) Invalid content: invalid backupdb extension: could not parse XQuery extension backupdb; please see the server error log for detail XDMP-UNEXPECTED: (err:XPST0003) Unexpected token syntax error, unexpected QName_; backupdb either is not a valid module or does not provide extension functions (delete, get, put, post) in the http://marklogic.com/rest-api/resource/backupdb namespace`

Here's the code for my extension:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";

module namespace backupdb =
    "http://marklogic.com/rest-api/resource/backupdb";

import module namespace admin = "http://marklogic.com/xdmp/admin"
    at "/MarkLogic/admin.xqy";


declare variable $dbname := "database-backup";
declare variable $s3bucket := "bucket-destination";

declare function backupdb:put(
    $context as map:map,
    $params  as map:map,
    $input   as document-node()*
) as document-node()?
{
  let $dbname := map:get($params, $dbname)
  let $s3bucket := map:get($params, $s3bucket)
  xdmp:database-backup(
    (:xdmp:database-forests(xdmp:database($dbname)), $s3bucket ):)
    xdmp:database-forests(xdmp:database($dbname)), "s3://bucketname/folder" )
        (: "s3://s3bucket/folder"); :)

};
```

Based on the answer from my other question that I got on stackoverflow I figured that I could use parameter and have curl to something like (after successful installation):

```
curl --anyauth --user "${USER}":"${pass}" -X PUT -d 'undefined'  'http://localhost:8040/v1/resources/backupdb?rs:database-backup=Documents&rs:bucket-destination=s3://bucket/folder'
```

POST method returns the same error.
What am I doing wrong here?

Any suggestions are welcome.

Thank you,
Ernest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also, you have a syntax error in your function (missing a return in the FLWOR) and you do not need to import the Admin library.

Comment: Thank you,
I updated my code with:
`return document { "Done"} `
but still the same issue.

Comment: specifically: `return xdmp:database-backup(...)`. Each [FLWOR statement needs to have a return](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/xquery/langoverview#id_11626)

Comment: Installation of new extension worked fine but now when I invoke curl to actually start backup <br/>
`curl --anyauth --user user:pass -X PUT -d 'undefined'  'http://localhost:8040/v1/resources/backupdb?rs:database-backup=Documents&rs:bucket-destination=s3://bucketname/folder'` <br/>
It returns `ERROR 500: Reason: Invalid coercion` but it does start, files are saved to s3 and I get bunch of messages in the log: <br/>
`XDMP-AS: (err:XPTY0004) $service($context, $service-params, $input) -- Invalid coercion: xs:unsignedLong("<logn-number>") as document-node()`
What does 'invalid coercion' means?

Comment: That means that your function does not return a document node.  The xdmp:database-backup returns a number (an xs:unsignedLong).  To turn that into a document node, you can wrap your whole function body in a document constructor.  something like:

Comment: You might want to try running your code on its own before deploying it.  It will be much easier to see syntax errors and so forth.  Query Console can help you to run the code on its own.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

The curl command above calls the resource service extension. You can't call the extension until you succeed in installing it.

Also,

- curl requires a PUT or POST request to specify the **content-type** of the payload with `-H 'content-type: _CONTENT_TYPE_HERE_';` when installing, the **content-type** should be **application/xquery**
- pass the local path to the **XQuery** source file with `-d @/path/to/xquerysource.xqy` when installing.

Here's the documentation on installing a resource service extension, which includes a curl example:

http://docs.marklogic.com/7.0/REST/PUT/v1/config/resources/%5Bname%5D

Here's the documentation on calling a resource service extension:

http://docs.marklogic.com/7.0/REST/PUT/v1/resources/%5Bname%5D

Hoping that helps,

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, curl command above was just an idea after successful installation.
Error above I'm getting from this command:

curl --anyauth --user user:pass -X PUT -i -H "Content-type: application/xquery" -d@"./backupdb.xqy" 'http://localhost:8040/v1/config/resources/backupdb'

Comment: On the MarkLogic discussion list, Danny Sokolsky commented on the syntax error in the example above. Maybe it would be better to raise this question in one venue instead of both to avoid confusion?

Comment: Will do. Thank you very much your support.