# How to monitor database backups in custom log when using rest-api extension in MarkLogic7?

Tags: marklogic

I have a bash script that calls rest-api extension and starts backups of all databases (code to rest-api extension can be found on my previous post: [MarkLogic 7 - database-backup with rest-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33246818/marklogic-7-database-backup-with-rest-api[a]))

The issue is that all information is dumped into `/var/opt/MarkLogic/Logs/ErrorLog.txt`, and these are not really errors.

I looked at `xdmp:trace`, `xdmp:query-trace`, `xdmp:log`, and tried adding simple `xdmp:query-trace(true())` before `xdmp:database-backup`, but that doesn't make a difference.

Looking around mailing list and http://developers.marklogic.com, it seems like people attempted something similar but I can't find right example on how it was done. Is there a way to redirect these messages to custom file or print all messages to stdout instead of into the log?

It would be just easier to monitor backups and not to dig through a lot of other system messages there.

Information that I'm looking for are: started, errors if any, completed.

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to set up polling, then create an endpoint that calls [xdmp:database-backup-status()](http://docs.marklogic.com/7.0/xdmp:database-backup-status). Pass in the job-id and check every n seconds until it's done.

Answer (score 0):

The `xdmp:query-trace` functions are for optimizing queries, and they are also sent to the file and system logs.

In the admin tools (Configure > Groups > Default) there is a setting titled `file log level` that controls the granularity of messages sent to the `ErrorLog.txt` file. If you change the value of that to `warning` or `error` (or higher), it will only include more critical logging information.

But since that will exclude potentially useful information from the log, a common solution is to monitor that log file through a filter, so you will still have the ability to sift through the excluded messages later. Many log tools have the ability to filter using simple string matching or regex. All of MarkLogic's log messages are prefixed with the log level ("Info:", "Notice:", "Warning:" etc.), so it's easy to filter the ones you don't want. You can do all this using `tail`, and there are lots of good solutions on SO about how to do that.

In addition to the `file log level` setting, there is a `system log level` setting that controls the granularity of messages sent to the operating system. If you have tools to monitor and filter this output that are preferable, you could use those instead.

Also, when you make a call to `xdmp:log`, you can pass as a second parameter the log level you want, which will only appear in logs where the granularity is set to that level or greater.

Comment: The thing is that I ran for loop to start backup on all databases in bash script and once job-id is returned next backup job is started.  Some databases are larger than others and one backup is still in progress where another 2 jobs are finished.   It's crazy to monitor these jobs from that log.  What if there are exceptions to jobs between?

Comment: Will the exception have job-id as well?

Comment: Typically, you get a stack trace along with any exception. So if `job-id` is a variable on the stack when the function throws the exception, then it should be included. You can also use `try/catch` to manage exceptions, and in the catch block throw your own custom error with exactly the info you want.